# How do I find data and replace it with data from another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Listed below is just one of many stores that are listed in my spreadsheet.

```
Column A1           |  Column B1
----------          |  ---------
Mays Dept Store 551 |   Mays Dept Store
```

How do I have excel find all the cells with the info from column A1 and replace it with the proper data of column B1.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough data/explanation to make clear what you seek to achieve. You could:

1. Use Find in Column A1 to locate ‘Mays Dept Store’ and replace with ‘551 Mays Dept Store’.
2. Use Filter to select ‘Mays Dept Store’ and replace with =B*row*, copied down as required (where ‘B’ is the reference to your Column B1 and *row* the row number of the first instance.)
3. If Column B1 always starts with a three digit number you could, temporarily, add a column with =LEFT(B*row*)&” “&”A*row*, copied down as required (where ‘A’ is the reference to your Column A1 and *row* the row number of the first instance) then for the results Copy/Paste Special/Values over the top of your Column A1 and delete the temporary additional column.
4. Use a LOOKUP to replace Column A1 values with the correct values from a table that for each pair matches the value to be substituted with its substitute.
5. Et al.